# Compiler created anonymous types: breakable behavior

Tags: dotfuscator

I have some client side HTTP RESTfull code which depends on the comfort that .net compiler generated anonymous types provide.

anonymous type example0 :

`string prop_1 = "strValue1"; int prop_2 = 5;`
`new { prop1 = prop_1, prop2 = prop_2};`

anonymous type example1 :

`new { prop1 = "strValue1", prop2 = 5};`

anonymous type example2 (also valid):

`string prop1 = "strValue1"; int prop2 = 5;`
`new { prop1, prop2};`

The problem here is, that the names of the compiler generated anonymous type's properties are very often important and can not be renamed. Specifically if the user has actively declared a property name for the anonymous type it could indicate that the name is actually important -even outside the assembly-

Dotfuscator Community currently by default renames the properties of the anonymous types.

One of such problematic area is the "ad hoc" building of JSON objects for serialization and network transfer. See code below.

This is some code, where I manually assemble an HTTP message content for WebAPI query. The correctness of the request depends on the exact property name. Anonymous type is used to not have to declare new -newer again to be used- types for every type of HTTP WebAPI query. The names username, password and request_token are important outside the application (for the API server)

```
string baseUrl = BASE_Address + BASE_Path + VALIDATE_REQUEST_TOKEN_W_LOGIN_Path;
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
query.Add(API_KEY_Key, _settings.ApiKey);
string requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUrl, query);
var jsonObj = new { username = username, password = password, request_token = requestToken };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
var content = new StringContent(json, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, mediaType: "application/json");
```

Expected behavior:
If Dotfuscator can not determine that it is safe to rename anonymous properties, then it should not rename it.

Consider:

1. If the user has actively named the anonymous types property, that it must be suspicious. Note that the sole reason for doing example0 instead of the shorter example2 (see above) is to get safety against type renaming in Visual Studio. With example0 even if you rename the variable prop_1 or prop_2 it will not break the anonymous typename and thus the resulting Json object
2. If the method or any called sub-method uses serialization than renaming the property surely will break the code. (as the typename in the serialized Json will depend on the original property name as there are no user declared attributes for serialization naming)

Now the question: can You recommend me some attribute or trick that preserves my current code but makes sure that Dotfuscator doesnt rename anything in the method/anonymous type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note*: I am answering here in my professional capacity as an employee of the developer of Dotfuscator

Dotfuscator Community has included a default reference rule for excluding properties from generated anonymous types since version 5.34. (You can download the latest version of Dotfuscator Community from [here](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads)). Alternatively, you can [define the rule](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/obfuscation_renaming.html#exclusion-rules) manually which is:

Exclude all properties from types named `.*AnonymousType.*` containing the custom attribute `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute`

```
<type name=".*AnonymousType.*" regex="true" excludetype="false">
    <customattribute name="System\.Runtime\.CompilerServices\.CompilerGeneratedAttribute" regex="true" />
    <propertymember name="*" regex="true" />
</type>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay Michael, I will try your suggestion later! 
Please note that I have a fresh Dotfuscator Community install (5.42), downloaded and set up as described on preemptive.com for  my Xamarin.Forms project.
When looking at the DotfuscatorConfig.xml in the projects folder, there is no entry similar what you have copied in. 
The UI lists that rule though...

Still as I have said, the obfuscated assembly has the compiler generated anonymous types renamed. ..

Comment: I have this in the config file:
      <referencerule rulekey="{6655B10A-FD58-462d-8D4F-5B1316DFF0FF}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{7D9C8B02-2383-420f-8740-A9760394C2C1}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{229FD6F8-5BCC-427b-8F72-A7A413ECDF1A}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{2B7E7C8C-A39A-4db8-9DFC-6AFD38509061}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{494EA3BA-B947-44B5-BEE8-A11CC85AAF9B}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{89769974-93E9-4e71-8D92-BE70E855ACFC}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{4D81E604-A545-4631-8B6D-C3735F793F80}" />

Comment: The referencerule rulekey for the Anonymous Type's properties rule is `{62bd3899-7d53-4336-8ca2-4e5dbae187d5}` If the config file was made before that rule was added as a default, it might not be there, checking it and resaving the config file (or manually adding it to the list in the config file) should cause those properties to retain their original metadata.

Comment: That last key seems to have done the trick. Note that it was not present in my DotfuscatorConfig.xml even though it was a fresh clean install with the steps from the homepage.